# How can you have multiple dependences for a single parameter in a widget.xml file?

Tags: xml, widget, parameter

Like many things with Magento widgets, this should be simple but clearly isn't.

How can I use the same depends logic but for multiple parameter values?

so

```
<depends>
    <parameter name="FAQAmount" value="1"/>
</depends>
```

Would be like this:

```
<depends>
    <parameter name="FAQAmount" value="1,2"/>
</depends>
```

Or this:

```
<depends>
    <parameter name="FAQAmount" value="1"/>
    <parameter name="FAQAmount" value="2"/>
    <parameter name="FAQAmount" value="3"/>
</depends>
```

This would be extremely useful but neither methods work, please help.